# using docker plugin on jenkins -

Tags: jenkins, docker

I'm trying to use the docker plugin on Jenkins to run an instance of an existing container.
Docker version 1.6.0, build 4749651

I've chosen "create container"
Entered the image id for the image name, and tried a host http://172.16.42.43:4243 and also tried an empty host.
I keep getting this error:

```
ERROR: Build step failed with exception
java.lang.NullPointerException: uri was not specified
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:204)
    at com.github.dockerjava.core.DockerClientConfig$DockerClientConfigBuilder.withUri(DockerClientConfig.java:406)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.dockerbuildstep.DockerBuilder$DescriptorImpl.createDockerClient(DockerBuilder.java:123)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.dockerbuildstep.DockerBuilder$DescriptorImpl.getDockerClient(DockerBuilder.java:201)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.dockerbuildstep.DockerBuilder.perform(DockerBuilder.java:71)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:779)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.build(Build.java:205)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:162)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:537)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1744)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:374)
Build step 'Execute Docker container' marked build as failure
```

Can someone tell me how to fix it?
Also, if anyone has used this plugin before, please let me know if this has ever worked.

Also tried the "Execute docker container"->start containers with the container id specified resulting in the same error.

Another approach:
I tried using the Execute shell plug in and I'm getting this error:

```
+ docker start d023eec1ff34
Post http:///var/run/docker.sock/v1.18/containers/d023eec1ff34/start: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: permission denied. Are you trying to connect to a TLS-enabled daemon without TLS?
time="2015-05-05T10:26:34-07:00" level=fatal msg="Error: failed to start one or more containers"
```

If I just go to the terminal, switch to jenkins user and run the docker start command, it works fine.
If someone know how to fix it this way, that would be great as well.

Comment: docker version ? Check the logs of docker (it may be in /var/log/docker.log or in /var/log/upstart/docker.log, depending on your OS), also try to start the Docker daemon in debug mode,. see --debug=true docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/cli/#daemon

Comment: May be this,extract from  http://serverfault.com/questions/639459/why-might-the-jenkins-user-not-have-permission-to-access-the-docker-unix-socket0 
 
I think giving jenkins group privileges to docker unix socket solves the issue. This can be modified with configuring docker daemon startup options in configuration file by adding this line

DOCKER_OPTS=' -G jenkins'

In ubuntu /etc/default/docker is the docker configuration file.

Comment: I tried adding that to the jenkins default. Also, I've tried adding jenkins user to the docker group. I did that on 2 machines with no luck.

Comment: yes. I restarted jenkins. Also, checked the logs. It's not logging anything that would correspond to the jenkins run. Why is it complaining about the uri when using the plugin?

Answer (score 15):

Assuming Docker is running on the same machine, make sure to run Docker with:

`-H tcp://127.0.0.1:4243 -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock`

Then go to **Manage Jenkins > Configuration > Configure System** then scroll down to **Docker Builder** and in the *Docker server REST url* enter `http://localhost:4243`

**Edited:** I had originally told Docker to listen on 0.0.0.0 which binds to all IP addresses and could allow connections from the outside if your Firewall lets the traffic through. So I updated it to bind to the loopback address instead. Also, the current version of the documentation recommends a different port but since you specify the port manually any port will do.

Comment: FYI 4243 is the old docker daemon port, the official one ended up being 2375 in the end

Comment: I'd highly recommend to use tcp://127.0.0.1 instead of 0.0.0.0 since you probably don't want to offer docker to the outside world.

Comment: @jonalv These are parameters for the Docker Daemon not the Docker Command Line Tool https://docs.docker.com/v1.10/engine/reference/commandline/daemon/

Comment: In my case, nothing seemed to work - I kept seeing the same error in the Jenkins logs when hitting the "Test" button in the Docker Builder configuration. Then I realized I needed to Save the configuration and then hit the Test button!

Answer (score 3):

You need to give Jenkins user permissions to use docker, buy adding it to docker group, run

```
sudo usermod -a -G docker jenkins
```