# What to do about NPE when trying to build docker image using jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, docker, docker-build

I am trying to build a docker image using the jenkins plugin `docker-build-step`. I am just trying the standard setup for creating an image:

[image]

However when I try to build I get a NullPointerException. At first I thought it was the same one as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30046507/using-docker-plugin-on-jenkins) but then I looked closer and saw that it was not (I didn't quite understand the answer of that question though so I have not managed to rule out definitely that it is not a related problem)

```
First time build. Skipping changelog.
ERROR: Build step failed with exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.github.dockerjava.jaxrs.DockerCmdExecFactoryImpl.init(DockerCmdExecFactoryImpl.java:105)
    at com.github.dockerjava.core.DockerClientImpl.withDockerCmdExecFactory(DockerClientImpl.java:64)
    at com.github.dockerjava.core.DockerClientBuilder.build(DockerClientBuilder.java:63)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.dockerbuildstep.DockerBuilder$DescriptorImpl.createDockerClient(DockerBuilder.java:132)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.dockerbuildstep.DockerBuilder$DescriptorImpl.getDockerClient(DockerBuilder.java:204)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.dockerbuildstep.DockerBuilder.perform(DockerBuilder.java:68)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:782)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.build(Build.java:205)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:162)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:534)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1738)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:410)
Build step 'Execute Docker command' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

What can I do about this exception?